FIPS kernel panics with "Failed to reset DRBG" during boot
System panics during FIPS integrity check at boot.  This is on new hardware, after a clean install of Ubuntu desktop 20.04.6.  I've tried both the 'fips' and 'fips-updates' options, both after clean installs.  The system will complete the boot when the 'fips=1' kernel command line arg is removed.  The processor is an AMD Ryzen 7 5800H.
Here is the kernel panic message:

Kernel panic - not syncing: random: Failed to reset DRBG (drbg_nopr_sha512): -2
CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.4.0-1024-fips #28+recert1-Ubuntu
Hardware name: AZW SER/SER, BIOS 5800H603 12/12/2023
Call Trace:
 dump_stack+0x6d/0x8b
 panic+0x101/0x2e3
 fips_drbg_init+0xa2/0xc6
 ? trace_event_define_fields_urandom_read+0x92/0x92
 do_one_initcall_0x4a/0x200
 kernel_init_freeable+0x1b2/0x255
 ? rest_init+0xb0/0xb0
 kernel_init+0xe/0x110
 ret_from_fork_0x22/0x40
Kernel Offset: 0x31c00000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff800000 0xffffffffbfffffff)
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: random: Failed to reset DRBG (drbg_nopr_sha512): -2 ]---

When booted without fips enabled, I see no problems with the system.  I've run a memory test without any errors.  I've tried booting with 'nordread' and 'random.trust_cpu=0'.  Not sure what else I can try.
Anyone have ideas of what might trigger such an event and/or something to try that may resolve the issue?
